# Game library for 2D animation JS browsergame

Tags: 2d, animation, browser-based-games, node.js, jquery

I am developing a 2D multiplayer online browsergame.

On the backend I have set up a Node.js server. Everything works perfectly.

On the frontend I will use jQuery and several libs for collision etc. so far.

I will not use canvas, Audio nor massive player numbers.

My question is, what is the **best library for 2D animations**?

Libs I know: craftyjs

"Animation" means: advanced moving/calculating of elements, keyboard movement, if possible collision detection

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. What was wrong with Crafty?

Comment: I am looking for the best one. Libs I have tested are craftyjs, just to let you know. There is nothing wrong with craftyjs. I just want your opinion. Why a downvote?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a Canvas instead of DOM elements. You might initially write more code, but in the long run you will have fewer problems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use Canvas I would look into [Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/) or [gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/). Note that both are plugins for jquery, which you are already using.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tested gameQuery also, forgot to add it. Will test Spritely.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [CraftyJS](http://craftyjs.com/), consider these possibilities:

- [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)
- [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com/)
- [MelonJS Framework](http://www.melonjs.org/)
- [Spaceport.io](http://spaceport.io/)
- [LimeJS](http://www.limejs.com/)

Which is "best" is going to take us into a discussion that's outside the scope of GameDev, as well as very subjective and very much dependent on your needs.  But the websites for these should give you an idea of their relative features.

Comment: Note `I will not use canvas`; the options you listed are for HTML5

Comment: @jhocking oops.  I just read the question as JS game framework alternatives.